# Configure "apiKey.properties" file in "shiro.ini" file in Heroku Java Web App

Tags: heroku, shiro, stormpath

I am trying to build up a Web Application in Heroku with Stormpath User Management addon and Apache Shiro.
When I go through the sample code its mentioned in "shiro.ini" file to provide the "apiKey.properties" file's path in property "stormpathClient.apiKeyFileLocation".
Please suggest how we can configure "apiKey.properties" file's path which contains STORMPATH API KEY ID and SECRET in Heroku application.

Comment: I have followed "http://shiro.apache.org/webapp-tutorial.html" URL and created a web app which runs perfect in local.When I started moving this project to Heroku ,the above problem came.In Heroku there is no option to store a file in a hidden folder but it gives those required fields in Config variables.So is there any way we can use the same variables in shiro.ini or we can replace apiKeyFileLocation property with some other value .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Heroku you can place the Api Key ID and Secret in Environment variables as described [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars).

So, what you can do:

1. Create the following class in your application:

```java
   package com.stormpath.sample.client;

   import java.util.Properties;

   public class ApiKeyEnvVariables extends Properties {

       public ApiKeyEnvVariables() {
           super.put("apiKey.id", System.getenv("STORMPATH_API_KEY_ID"));
           super.put("apiKey.secret", System.getenv("STORMPATH_API_KEY_SECRET"));
       }
   }
```

2. Change your `shiro.ini` to look like this:

```
 apiKeyProps = com.stormpath.sample.client.ApiKeyEnvVariables
 #stormpathClient.apiKeyFileLocation = /Users/XXXX/.stormpath/apiKey.properties
 stormpathClient.apiKeyProperties = $apiKeyProps
```

3. Set `STORMPATH_API_KEY_ID` and `STORMPATH_API_KEY_SECRET` environment variables. For example:

```sh
   heroku config:set STORMPATH_API_KEY_ID=2JQQCIG5E8EKN4DKBT7R151
   heroku config:set STORMPATH_API_KEY_ID=1oYULQMkS3dwKkl6wtbNd93IyUrRehCsEJJrIrMwuI0
```

Now, when your app starts, Stormpath will automatically pick the Api Key Id and Secret from the environment variables.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Hi Mario, I tried above solution .Its working perfectly in Heroku with Shiro-StormPath .